# Highchart - Show histogram results using waterfall style rendering

Tags: highcharts

We want to use the calculation options that histogram chart offers out of box but want to actually render the chart to look like waterfall. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. We can use the calculated data from the histogram series and use it to add dynamically as a waterfall type.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ofezLb2w/

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        let chart = this,
          dataX = chart.series[0].processedXData,
          dataY = chart.series[0].processedYData,
          WFData = dataX.map((d, i) => [d, dataY[i]]);


        chart.series[0].destroy()
        chart.addSeries({
          data: WFData,
          type: 'waterfall',
          xAxis: 1,
          yAxis: 1,
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load